# How do I make Material UI Datagrid NoRowsOverlay component clickable?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dropzone, mui-x

I would like to override the Datagrid's NoRowsOverlay component with my custom one, which uses [react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.js.org/):

```
<GridOverlay
  {...getRootProps()}
  className={clsx(classes.zone, {
    [classes.valid]: isDragAccept,
    [classes.invalid]: isDragReject
  })}
>
  <input {...getInputProps()} />
  {isDragActive
    ? (
      <Typography variant='h6'>
        {isDragAccept ? 'Drop the file here.' : 'Invalid file type.'}
      </Typography>
      )
    : (
      <Typography variant='h6'>
        Drop CSV file here or click to upload.
      </Typography>
      )}
</GridOverlay>
```

I'm overriding the component like so:

```
<DataGrid
  autoHeight
  columns={getColumns(classes)}
  components={{
    NoRowsOverlay: DropZone
  }}
  disableColumnMenu
  disableSelectionOnClick
  hideFooter
  rows={devices}
/>
```

I cannot figure out why drag&drop and also clicking on dropzone does not work anymore.
Replacing `GridOverlay` with regular `div` also does not work. Dropzone component works as long as rendered outside the `DataGrid`. Any ideas?

Comment: were you ever able to solve this?

Comment: @daniellanger sorry, but no.

Comment: I just experienced a similar issue. I was able to get it to work by giving my overlays wrapper `zIndex: 99` and `position: relative`. `style={{ zIndex: 99, position: 'relative'}` `position: absolute` also works

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently where I placed a button in my custom overlay, but it was unclickable.

The cause of the problem for me was that the DataGrid was inside a modal, causing the button to be unclickable whenever the overlay was active. However, I fixed the issue by giving my overlay component a higher `z-index`.

```
    <GridOverlay {...getRootProps()}
          style={{ zIndex: 5}}
          //Or add it to your classes.zone styles
          className={clsx(classes.zone, {
            [classes.valid]: isDragAccept,
            [classes.invalid]: isDragReject
          })}
        >
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          {isDragActive
            ? (
              <Typography variant='h6'>
                {isDragAccept ? 'Drop the file here.' : 'Invalid file type.'}
              </Typography>
              )
            : (
              <Typography variant='h6'>
                Drop CSV file here or click to upload.
              </Typography>
              )}
        </GridOverlay>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add both z-index and pointer-events classes:

```
  <GridOverlay style={{ zIndex: 5, pointerEvents: 'all' }}>
    ...
  </GridOverlay>
```